# Changing output files location in NuGet

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, nuget

How can I change `AngularJS` or another project's output files location. For example the `.js`  files of `AngularJS`'s default location is `~/scripts` folder but I want to move it to `~/content/js` folder.

It is easy to move files but when I try to update `AngularJS`, the new `.js` files go to default location. Is there any workaround or way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with NuGet. The folder location for files is defined by the NuGet package creator.